# Вопросы по AJAX, как работает?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

В Wordpress делаю вызов функции с AJAX запросом.
Объясните, пожалуйста, почему при успешном запросе НЕ БУДЕТ выведено по порядку 1 2 3, а выведется 1 3 2.
Не смог сформулировать лучше, с каким то точным кодом, надеюсь поймёте. Спасибо

```
function double() {
  var data = {
    action: 'doubleReg',
  };
  alert(1);

  $.post(myajax.url, data, function() {
    alert(2);
  }

  alert(3);
}
double();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что функция `$.post` вызывается, запоминает внутри себя обработчик

```
function() {alert(2);}
```

и возвращается. Обработчик будет вызван позже (асинхронно), когда придет ответ от сервера.

Comment: А можно как то сделать AJAX синхронно, что бы пока он не получит ответ, код дальше не выполнялся? или это уже полная глупость?

Comment: @Gagablik Первая буква "А" в слове AJAX означает - "асинхронный".